# Computing an md5 hash of a data structure

Tags: python, data-structures, md5

I want to compute an md5 hash not of a string, but of an entire data structure.  I understand the mechanics of a way to do this (dispatch on the type of the value, canonicalize dictionary key order and other randomness, recurse into sub-values, etc).  But it seems like the kind of operation that would be generally useful, so I'm surprised I need to roll this myself.

Is there some simpler way in Python to achieve this?

UPDATE: pickle has been suggested, and it's a good idea, but pickling doesn't canonicalize dictionary key order:

```
>>> import cPickle as pickle
>>> import hashlib, random 
>>> for i in range(10):
...  k = [i*i for i in range(1000)]
...  random.shuffle(k)
...  d = dict.fromkeys(k, 1)
...  p = pickle.dumps(d)
...  print hashlib.md5(p).hexdigest()
...
51b5855799f6d574c722ef9e50c2622b
43d6b52b885f4ecb4b4be7ecdcfbb04e
e7be0e6d923fe1b30c6fbd5dcd3c20b9
aebb2298be19908e523e86a3f3712207
7db3fe10dcdb70652f845b02b6557061
43945441efe82483ba65fda471d79254
8e4196468769333d170b6bb179b4aee0
951446fa44dba9a1a26e7df9083dcadf
06b09465917d3881707a4909f67451ae
386e3f08a3c1156edd1bd0f3862df481
```

Comment: I feel a little dirty for suggesting it, but could you md5sum the [pickled](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) version of your data structure?

Comment: There's nothing dirty about pickling, it just doesn't satisfy the needs of a hash.

Comment: Awww, bummer. I was hoping it'd save you a huge amount of effort. :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[bencode](https://pypi.org/project/bencode/1.0/) sorts dictionaries so:

```
import hashlib
import bencode
data = ['only', 'lists', [1,2,3], 
'dictionaries', {'a':0,'b':1}, 'numbers', 47, 'strings']
data_md5 = hashlib.md5(bencode.bencode(data)).hexdigest()
print data_md5
```

prints:

```
af1b88ca9fd8a3e828b40ed1b9a2cb20
```

Comment: Yes, bencode seems to do exactly the thing I imagined, but with the extra feature of being reversible.

Comment: It should be noted that [`bencode`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bencode/1.0) isn't a standard Python 2 or 3 module.

Comment: Its also doesn't encode as many data structures as pickle :-(

Comment: I don't think this should be the accepted solution anymore.  bencode depends on a module BTL that doesn't seem to be readily available anymore (cf. https://github.com/bittorrent/bencode/issues/3).

Comment: @DavidKaufman The issue the reporter finds there is that how relative imports work changed. The module bencode consists of a directory with a `__init__.py` file that imports from the `BTL.py` file in the directory. The BTL module is right there in the bencode package. It's just that now imports like that have to use the dot prefixed form. But there are older versions of the bencode module that are a single self-contained file.

Comment: @DavidKaufman If you think that, tell the asker to reconsider. I only presented an option. And it might have not been even a good one.

Answer (score 105):

[json.dumps()](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) can sort dictionaries by key. So you don't need other dependencies:

```
import hashlib
import json

data = ['only', 'lists', [1,2,3], 'dictionaries', {'a':0,'b':1}, 'numbers', 47, 'strings']
data_md5 = hashlib.md5(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

print(data_md5)
```

Prints:

```
87e83d90fc0d03f2c05631e2cd68ea02
```

Comment: Excellent, and hashlib and json are always present with python

Comment: Nice solution, but bear in mind that some data types cannot be converted to JSON without **extra work** - `datetime` being the most common.

`data = ['1234', 234, datetime.datetime(2013,1,1)]`
`hashlib.md5(json.dumps(a, sort_keys=True)).hexdigest()`

results in

`TypeError: datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 0) is not JSON serializable`

Comment: @Boris: It's fairly easy to get the `json` module to serialize many more data types (including instances of most user-defined classes as well as `datetime.datetime` instances) as shown in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18561055/355230) to the question [_Making object JSON serializable with regular encoder_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478287/making-object-json-serializable-with-regular-encoder).

Comment: In python3 there will be a `TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing` 

So use this `data_md5 = hashlib.md5(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()`

Comment: Very clever solution for a deterministic hashing function in pure Python

Comment: Is the dict order issue still a thing? Python 3.7 and later [preserves insertion order of a dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

Answer (score 8):

I ended up writing it myself as I thought I would have to:

```
class Hasher(object):
    """Hashes Python data into md5."""
    def __init__(self):
        self.md5 = md5()

    def update(self, v):
        """Add `v` to the hash, recursively if needed."""
        self.md5.update(str(type(v)))
        if isinstance(v, basestring):
            self.md5.update(v)
        elif isinstance(v, (int, long, float)):
            self.update(str(v))
        elif isinstance(v, (tuple, list)):
            for e in v:
                self.update(e)
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            keys = v.keys()
            for k in sorted(keys):
                self.update(k)
                self.update(v[k])
        else:
            for k in dir(v):
                if k.startswith('__'):
                    continue
                a = getattr(v, k)
                if inspect.isroutine(a):
                    continue
                self.update(k)
                self.update(a)

    def digest(self):
        """Retrieve the digest of the hash."""
        return self.md5.digest()
```

Comment: How would you handle the ``set`` type? Out of my head I'd say, the same way as you handle tuples and lists, with the difference being that it should first be ``sorted()``. Would you agree?

Comment: Yes, sorted(v) would be the way to go.

Comment: Beware, calls to `update()` essentially concatenate. So this will hash `{'test': 1}` to the same thing as `['test', 1]` and `test1`.

Which may or may not be the desired behaviour.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/md5.html

Comment: @RossHemsley You overlooked `self.md5.update(str(type(v)))`

Comment: True, that helps. It might be worth noting that there are edge cases in doing it this way.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the builtin [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) that will cover some more cases than the proposed `json.dumps()` solution. For example `datetime`-objects will be handled correctly.

Your example rewritten to use `pprint` instead of `json`:

```
>>> import hashlib, random, pprint
>>> for i in range(10):
...     k = [i*i for i in range(1000)]
...     random.shuffle(k)
...     d = dict.fromkeys(k, 1)
...     print hashlib.md5(pprint.pformat(d)).hexdigest()
... 
b4e5de6e1c4f3c6540e962fd5b1891db
b4e5de6e1c4f3c6540e962fd5b1891db
b4e5de6e1c4f3c6540e962fd5b1891db
b4e5de6e1c4f3c6540e962fd5b1891db
b4e5de6e1c4f3c6540e962fd5b1891db
b4e5de6e1c4f3c6540e962fd5b1891db
b4e5de6e1c4f3c6540e962fd5b1891db
b4e5de6e1c4f3c6540e962fd5b1891db
b4e5de6e1c4f3c6540e962fd5b1891db
b4e5de6e1c4f3c6540e962fd5b1891db
```

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: this won't work for dictionaries due to key order randomness. Sorry, I've not thought of it.

```
import hashlib
import cPickle as pickle
data = ['anything', 'you', 'want']
data_pickle = pickle.dumps(data)
data_md5 = hashlib.md5(data_pickle).hexdigest()
```

This should work for any python data structure, and for objects as well.

Comment: Pickling doesn't fix the randomness in dictionary keys.

Answer (score 2):

While it does require a dependency on `joblib`, I've found that [`joblib.hashing.hash(object)`](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/blob/master/joblib/hashing.py#L246) works very well and is designed for use with `joblib`'s disk caching mechanism. Empirically it seems to be producing consistent results from run to run, even on data that `pickle` mixes up on different runs.

Alternatively, you might be interested in `artemis-ml`'s [`compute_fixed_hash`](https://github.com/QUVA-Lab/artemis/blob/master/artemis/general/hashing.py#L25) function, which theoretically hashes objects in a way that is consistent across runs. However, I've not tested it myself.

Sorry for posting millions of years after the original question

Answer (score 0):

ROCKY way: Put all your struct items in one parent entity (if not already), recurse and sort/canonicalize/etc them, then calculate the md5 of its `repr`.

Comment: I'd much rather not change the data structure to accommodate the hashing task.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating checksum upon a JSON serialization is a good idea as it's easy to implement and easy to extend for some Python data structures that are natively not JSON serializable.

This is my revised version of @webwurst's answer, which generates the JSON string in chunks that are immediately consumed to calculate the final checksum, to prevent excessive memory consumption for a large object:

```py
import hashlib
import json

def checksum(obj, method='md5', *,
        # If dicts with different key order are to be treated as identical.
        # Set False otherwise.
        sort_keys=True,

        # A dict with circular referencing objects can never be hashed and is
        # out of scope of this topic. Skip checking such cases to save an
        # in-memory mapping as we don't expect them. Set True otherwise.
        check_circular=False,

        # Set True to output bytes instead of hex string to save memory, if the
        # checksum is used only for internal comparison and not to be output.
        ouput_bytes=False,
        ):
    m = hashlib.new(method)
    encoder = json.JSONEncoder(
        check_circular=check_circular,
        sort_keys=sort_keys,
        ensure_ascii=False,  # don't escape Unicode chars to save bytes
        separators=(',', ':'),  # reduce default spaces to be more compact
    )
    for chunk in encoder.iterencode(obj):
        m.update(chunk.encode('UTF-8'))

    if ouput_bytes:
        return m.digest()

    return m.hexdigest()

def test():
    data = [
        'only',
        'tuples', ('foo', 'bar'),
        'lists', [1,2,3],
        'dictionaries', {'a':0,'b':1},
        'numbers', 47,
        'strings', '哈囉世界',
    ]
    chk = checksum(data)
    print(chk)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```