# Making object JSON serializable with regular encoder

Tags: python, json, serialization, monkeypatching

The regular way of JSON-serializing custom non-serializable objects is to subclass `json.JSONEncoder` and then pass a custom encoder to `json.dumps()`.

It usually looks like this:

```
class CustomEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Foo):
            return obj.to_json()

        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

print(json.dumps(obj, cls=CustomEncoder))
```

What I'm trying to do, is to make something serializable with the default encoder. I looked around but couldn't find anything.
My thought is that there would be some field in which the encoder looks at to determine the json encoding. Something similar to `__str__`. Perhaps a `__json__` field.
Is there something like this in python?

I want to make one class of a module I'm making to be JSON serializable to everyone that uses the package without them worrying about implementing their own [trivial] custom encoders.

Comment: I don't see anything like that in the source of the `json` module's [`encoder.py`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/18a3528f661d/Lib/json/encoder.py) file.

Comment: For those wondering why something like `__json__` isn't already supported, see e.g. these discussions: [cpython issue #79292](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/79292), [cpython issue #71549](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/71549)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

As I said in a comment to your question, after looking at the `json` module's source code, it does not appear to lend itself to doing what you want. However the goal could be achieved by what is known as [*monkey-patching*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey-patch)
(see question [*What is a monkey patch?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-a-monkey-patch)).
This could be done in your package's `__init__.py` initialization script and would affect all subsequent `json` module serialization since modules are generally only loaded once and the result is cached in `sys.modules`.

The patch changes the default json encoder's `default` method—the default `default()`.

Here's an example implemented as a standalone module for simplicity's sake:

Module: `make_json_serializable.py`

```
""" Module that monkey-patches json module when it's imported so
JSONEncoder.default() automatically checks for a special "to_json()"
method and uses it to encode the object if found.
"""
from json import JSONEncoder

def _default(self, obj):
    return getattr(obj.__class__, "to_json", _default.default)(obj)

_default.default = JSONEncoder.default  # Save unmodified default.
JSONEncoder.default = _default # Replace it.
```

Using it is trivial since the patch is applied by simply importing the module.

Sample client script:

```
import json
import make_json_serializable  # apply monkey-patch

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def to_json(self):  # New special method.
        """ Convert to JSON format string representation. """
        return '{"name": "%s"}' % self.name

foo = Foo('sazpaz')
print(json.dumps(foo))  # -> "{\"name\": \"sazpaz\"}"
```

To retain the object type information, the special method can also include it in the string returned:

```
        return ('{"type": "%s", "name": "%s"}' %
                 (self.__class__.__name__, self.name))
```

Which produces the following JSON that now includes the class name:

```
"{\"type\": \"Foo\", \"name\": \"sazpaz\"}"
```

***Magick Lies Here***

Even better than having the replacement `default()` look for a specially named method, would be for it to be able to serialize most Python objects *automatically*, including user-defined class instances, without needing to add a special method. After researching a number of alternatives, the following — based on an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8230373/355230) by @Raymond Hettinger to another question — which uses the `pickle` module, seemed closest to that ideal to me:

Module: `make_json_serializable2.py`

```
""" Module that imports the json module and monkey-patches it so
JSONEncoder.default() automatically pickles any Python objects
encountered that aren't standard JSON data types.
"""
from json import JSONEncoder
import pickle

def _default(self, obj):
    return {'_python_object': pickle.dumps(obj)}

JSONEncoder.default = _default  # Replace with the above.
```

Of course everything can't be pickled—extension types for example. However there are ways defined to handle them via the pickle protocol by writing special methods—similar to what you suggested and I described earlier—but doing that would likely be necessary for a far fewer number of cases.

**Deserializing**

Regardless, using the pickle protocol also means it would be fairly easy to reconstruct the original Python object by providing a custom `object_hook` function argument on any `json.loads()` calls that used any `'_python_object'` key in the dictionary passed in, whenever it has one. Something like:

```
def as_python_object(dct):
    try:
        return pickle.loads(str(dct['_python_object']))
    except KeyError:
        return dct

pyobj = json.loads(json_str, object_hook=as_python_object)
```

If this has to be done in many places, it might be worthwhile to define a wrapper function that automatically supplied the extra keyword argument:

```
json_pkloads = functools.partial(json.loads, object_hook=as_python_object)

pyobj = json_pkloads(json_str)
```

Naturally, this could be monkey-patched it into the `json` module as well, making the function the default `object_hook` (instead of `None`).

I got the idea for using `pickle` from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8230373/355230) by [Raymond Hettinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1001643/raymond-hettinger) to another JSON serialization question, whom I consider exceptionally credible as well as an official source (as in Python core developer).

#### Portability to Python 3

The code above does not work as shown in Python 3 because `json.dumps()` returns a `bytes` object which the `JSONEncoder` can't handle. However the approach is still valid. A simple way to workaround the issue is to `latin1` "decode" the value returned from `pickle.dumps()` and then "encode" it from `latin1` before passing it on to `pickle.loads()` in the `as_python_object()` function. This works because arbitrary binary strings are valid `latin1` which can always be decoded to Unicode and then encoded back to the original string again (as pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22621777/355230) by [Sven Marnach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279627/sven-marnach)).

<sup>(Although the following works fine in Python 2, the `latin1` decoding and encoding it does is superfluous.)</sup>

```
from decimal import Decimal

class PythonObjectEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        return {'_python_object': pickle.dumps(obj).decode('latin1')}


def as_python_object(dct):
    try:
        return pickle.loads(dct['_python_object'].encode('latin1'))
    except KeyError:
        return dct


class Foo(object):  # Some user-defined class.
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if type(other) is type(self):  # Instances of same class?
            return self.name == other.name
        return NotImplemented

    __hash__ = None


data = [1,2,3, set(['knights', 'who', 'say', 'ni']), {'key':'value'},
        Foo('Bar'), Decimal('3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169')]
j = json.dumps(data, cls=PythonObjectEncoder, indent=4)
data2 = json.loads(j, object_hook=as_python_object)
assert data == data2  # both should be same
```

Comment: This is clearly a good (the?) solution. But it induces one (unavoidable) limitation: this patch should be imported to load such a serialized data. So what would be the rules to follow in order for the returned content to still be loadable by standard json (not completely obviously, but which does not fail)?

Comment: @Juh_: As long as the string returned by the `to_json()` method is valid JSON, it will be loadable by a standard json parser, regardless of whether the patch itself has been imported or not.

Comment: Thank you @martineau for this code. By the way, do you think it's possible to subclass `JSONEncoder` to do this shortly : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21866774/pretty-print-json-dumps ?

Comment: @Basj: No, I don't think it's feasible to subclass `JSONEncoder` to pretty-print JSON dumps that way shown in your question.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer.

Answer (score 14):

You can extend the dict class like so:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import json

class Serializable(dict):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # hack to fix _json.so make_encoder serialize properly
        self.__setitem__('dummy', 1)

    def _myattrs(self):
        return [
            (x, self._repr(getattr(self, x))) 
            for x in self.__dir__() 
            if x not in Serializable().__dir__()
        ]

    def _repr(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, (str, int, float, list, tuple, dict)):
            return value
        else:
            return repr(value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<%s.%s object at %s>' % (
            self.__class__.__module__,
            self.__class__.__name__,
            hex(id(self))
        )

    def keys(self):
        return iter([x[0] for x in self._myattrs()])

    def values(self):
        return iter([x[1] for x in self._myattrs()])

    def items(self):
        return iter(self._myattrs())
```

Now to make your classes serializable with the regular encoder, extend 'Serializable':

```
class MySerializableClass(Serializable):

    attr_1 = 'first attribute'
    attr_2 = 23

    def my_function(self):
        print('do something here')


obj = MySerializableClass()
```

`print(obj)` will print something like:

```
<__main__.MySerializableClass object at 0x1073525e8>
```

`print(json.dumps(obj, indent=4))` will print something like:

```
{
    "attr_1": "first attribute",
    "attr_2": 23,
    "my_function": "<bound method MySerializableClass.my_function of <__main__.MySerializableClass object at 0x1073525e8>>"
}
```

Comment: `# hack to fix _json.so make_encoder serialize properly` <-- Whoa how does this work? Also if I set class members to other serializable classes, then the `repr()` value of the class is emitted instead of its dict

Comment: @inetknght Sorry, just saw this. I wrote this a long time back, and I haven't worked with python in quite a bit. As for the `# hack ...` I remember looking at the `json.dumps` implementation in the library code. If i remember correctly, It was using a native implementation `_json.so`. If that could not be used, it would fall back to the python implementation (which is possibly slower). `_json.so` would not serialize the class if there were no values in the underlying `dict`. So when I added the dummy value, it called `items()` or whatever like it should.

Comment: and regarding your second problem, you may need to play around with `__repr__` (or remove it altogether) or check if a nested value is a `dict` on serializing. Like I said, I'm a little rusty, I need to take a look at how `json.dumps()` works again

Answer (score 5):

I suggest putting the hack into the class definition. This way, once the class is defined, it supports JSON. Example:

```
import json

class MyClass( object ):

    def _jsonSupport( *args ):
        def default( self, xObject ):
            return { 'type': 'MyClass', 'name': xObject.name() }

        def objectHook( obj ):
            if 'type' not in obj:
                return obj
            if obj[ 'type' ] != 'MyClass':
                return obj
            return MyClass( obj[ 'name' ] )
        json.JSONEncoder.default = default
        json._default_decoder = json.JSONDecoder( object_hook = objectHook )

    _jsonSupport()

    def __init__( self, name ):
        self._name = name

    def name( self ):
        return self._name

    def __repr__( self ):
        return '<MyClass(name=%s)>' % self._name

myObject = MyClass( 'Magneto' )
jsonString = json.dumps( [ myObject, 'some', { 'other': 'objects' } ] )
print "json representation:", jsonString

decoded = json.loads( jsonString )
print "after decoding, our object is the first in the list", decoded[ 0 ]
```

Comment: A notable limitation of this approach is that, as currently written, it doesn't play well with others in the sense that it wouldn't work to have more than one class using this approach at a time because otherwise they would step on each others JSON support code. Even if it did work in such a situation, it would require similar support code to be duplicated and placed in each class. It might be possible to fix both of these issues, however.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with overriding `JSONEncoder().default` is that you can do it only once. If you stumble upon anything a special data type that does not work with that pattern (like if you use a strange encoding). With the pattern below, you can always make your class JSON serializable, provided that the class field you want to serialize is serializable itself (and can be added to a python list, barely anything). Otherwise, you have to apply recursively the same pattern to your json field (or extract the serializable data from it):

```
# base class that will make all derivatives JSON serializable:
class JSONSerializable(list): # need to derive from a serializable class.

  def __init__(self, value = None):
    self = [ value ]

  def setJSONSerializableValue(self, value):
    self = [ value ]

  def getJSONSerializableValue(self):
    return self[1] if len(self) else None


# derive  your classes from JSONSerializable:
class MyJSONSerializableObject(JSONSerializable):

  def __init__(self): # or any other function
    # .... 
    # suppose your__json__field is the class member to be serialized. 
    # it has to be serializable itself. 
    # Every time you want to set it, call this function:
    self.setJSONSerializableValue(your__json__field)
    # ... 
    # ... and when you need access to it,  get this way:
    do_something_with_your__json__field(self.getJSONSerializableValue())


# now you have a JSON default-serializable class:
a = MyJSONSerializableObject()
print json.dumps(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you can't write a `serialize` function for your own class? You implement the custom encoder inside the class itself and allow "people" to call the serialize function that will essentially return `self.__dict__` with functions stripped out.

edit:

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/python-how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable) agrees with me, that the most simple way is write your own method and return the json serialized data that you want. They also recommend to try jsonpickle, but now you're adding an additional dependency for beauty when the correct solution comes built in.

Comment: I suspect the reason is because if the stock `json.dumps()` method (or `json.JSONEncoder`) were smarter one or the other would automatically look for a special object method, then it would be unnecessary to pass it a special encoder -- something which is not always possible. This is how the `print` statement/function works. It looks for a `__str__()` object method and uses it if one is found. This makes it very easy to print instances of classes, even when they're inside something else like a `list` or `dict`.

Comment: @martineau he'll probably have to submit a change for the json module in the standard library to do it the way he wants. Looking at the source for json it's just not there for this.

Answer (score 0):

For production environment, prepare rather own module of `json` with your own custom encoder, to make it clear that you overrides something.
Monkey-patch is not recommended, but you can do monkey patch in your testenv.

For example,

```
class JSONDatetimeAndPhonesEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, (datetime.date, datetime.datetime)):
            return obj.date().isoformat()
        elif isinstance(obj, basestring):
            try:
                number = phonenumbers.parse(obj)
            except phonenumbers.NumberParseException:
                return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
            else:
                return phonenumbers.format_number(number, phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL)
        else:
            return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

you want:

payload = json.dumps(your_data, cls=JSONDatetimeAndPhonesEncoder)

or:

payload = your_dumps(your_data)

or:

payload = your_json.dumps(your_data)

however in testing environment, go a head:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def testenv_monkey_patching():
    json._default_encoder = JSONDatetimeAndPhonesEncoder()
```

which will apply your encoder to all `json.dumps` occurrences.

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach will not work for some standard classes like str, dict, tuple, etc.. It is not easy to understand it from the documentation: ```json.JSONEncoder [skip] Supports the following objects and types by default. [skip] To extend this to recognize **other** objects, subclass and implement a default() method```. What a disappointment..

Comment: @NikO'Lai: I've added custom recognition for 2 types, as an example. any other type will work in default way and with default encoder, which is `json.JSONEncoder`