# Pretty-print write dictionary to file

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a dictionary with `(string, list)` as key-value pair (list may be empty), which I write to file using:

```
with open(out_file, "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

If I don't use `indent=4`, everything is in the same line.

Problem: Output is like

```
{
    "key_1": [
            1,
            2,
    ],
    "key_2": []
}
```

while I wanted (mainly because the lists usually have around 10 numbers only, and easier to view on same line):

```
{
    "key_1": [1, 2],
    "key_2": []
}
```

Any idea have I can achieve this?

Comment: This post maybe also helps you: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21866774/pretty-print-json-dumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21866774/pretty-print-json-dumps).

Comment: @BramDekker that was precisely to the point, thank you :)