# Serializing binary data in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, serialization, binary

I have some binary data which is in Python in the form of an array of byte strings.

Is there a portable way to serialize this data that other languages could read?

JSON loses because I just found out that it has no real way to store binary data; its strings are expected to be Unicode.

I don't want to use `pickle` because I don't want the security risk, and that limits its use to other Python programs.

Any advice? I would really like to use a builtin library (or at least one that's part of the standard Anaconda distribution).

Comment: Base64? Good enough for porn pictures on Usenet in the 90s . . .

Comment: yeah, base64 is my fallback approach. I just was hoping there was a one-step solution out there already.

Comment: Can't you just write them as they are?  "Binary string" sounds like it is already serialised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just need the binary data in the strings and can recover the boundaries between the individual strings easily, you could just write them to a file directly, as raw strings.

If you can't recover the string boundaries easily, JSON seems like a good option:

```
a = [b"abc\xf3\x9c\xc6", b"xyz"]
serialised = json.dumps([s.decode("latin1") for s in a])
print [s.encode("latin1") for s in json.loads(serialised)]
```

will print

```
['abc\xf3\x9c\xc6', 'xyz']
```

The trick here is that arbitrary binary strings are valid `latin1`, so they can always be decoded to Unicode and encoded back to the original string again.

Comment: The boundaries aren't impossible to recreate, but they're not easy to get either. (the [packet-framing problem](http://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/113.php) ) So yeah, I can live with JSON's overhead given its widespread nature.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57041412