# Byte file conversion via python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, decode, encode

Is there any simple way for me to read the contents of a binary file as a binary string, turn it into a normal (utf-8) string, do some operations with it, turn it back into a binary string and write it into a binary file? I tried doing something as simple as:

```
a_file = open('image1.png', 'rb')
text = b''
for a_line in a_file:
    text += a_line
a_file.close()
text2 = text.decode('utf-8')
text3 = text2.encode()
a_file = open('image2.png', 'wb')
a_file.write(text3)
a_file.close()
```

but I get 'Unicode can not decode bytes in position...'

What am I doing terribly wrong?

Comment: Why do you think a PNG file would contain text?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22621777/355230) to another question may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The utf8 format has enough structure that random arrangements of bytes are not valid UTF-8. The best approach would be to simply work with the bytes read from the file (which you can extract in one step with `text = a_file.read()`). Binary strings (type `bytes`) have all the string methods you'll want, even text-oriented ones like `isupper()` or `swapcase()`. And then there's `bytearray`, a mutable counterpart to the `bytes` type.

If for some reason you *really* want to turn your bytes into a `str` object, use a pure 8-bit encoding like `Latin1`. You'll get a *unicode* string, which is what you are really after. (UTF-8 is just an encoding for Unicode-- a very different thing.)

Comment: And note, if you settle on a working encoding (e.g. `latin-1`), you don't need to handle the encode/decode yourself in Python 3. Just change `open('image1.png', 'rb')` to `open('image1.png', 'r', encoding='latin-1')`, and for the output, `open('image2.png', 'w', encoding='latin-1')` and you can read and write without bothering to manually `encode`/`decode`; it will have been decoded to `str` for you on read, and will encode the `str` for you on write.

Comment: Good point; though opening the files in binary mode makes the code a little more transparent... I'm not sure the OP should be converting to `str` at all.