# Encoding and decoding binary data for inclusion into JSON with Python 3

Tags: python, json, encoding, base64, binary-data

I need to decide on a schema for including binary elements into a message object so that it can be decoded again on the receiving end (In my situation a consumer on an Rabbit MQ / AMQP queue).

I decided against multipart MIME encoding over JSON mostly because it seems like using Thor's hammer to push in a thumb tack.  I decided against manually joining parts (binary and JSON concatenated together) mostly because every time a new requirement arises it is a whole re-design.  JSON with the binary encoded in one of the fields seems like an elegant solution.

My seemingly working (confirmed by comparing MD5-sum of sent and received data) solution is doing the following:

```
def json_serialiser(byte_obj):
    if isinstance(byte_obj, (bytes, bytearray)):
        # File Bytes to Base64 Bytes then to String
        return base64.b64encode(byte_obj).decode('utf-8')
    raise ValueError('No encoding handler for data type ' + type(byte_obj))


def make_msg(filename, filedata):
    d = {"filename": filename,
         "datalen": len(filedata),
         "data": filedata}
    return json.dumps(d, default=json_serialiser)
```

On the receiving end I simply do:

```
def parse_json(msg):
    d = json.loads(msg)
    data = d.pop('data')
    return base64.b64decode(data), d


def file_callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    filedata, fileinfo = parse_json(body)
    print('File Name:', fileinfo.get("filename"))
    print('Received File Size', len(filedata))
```

My google-fu left me unable to confirm whether what I am doing is in fact valid.  In particular I am concerned whether the line that produces the string from the binary data for inclusion into JSON is correct, eg the line
`return base64.b64encode(byte_obj).decode('utf-8')`

And it seems that I am able to take a shortcut with the decoding back to binary data as the `base64.b64decode()` method handles the UTF-8 data as if it is ASCII - As one would expect it to be coming from the output of `base64.b64encode()` ... But is this a valid assumption in all cases?

Mostly I'm surprised at not being able to find any examples online of doing this.  Perhaps my google patience are still on holiday!

Comment: Another option is to decode the bytes directly as `'latin1'`, as described e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22621777), *instead* of using `base64`. For example `byte_obj.decode('latin1')`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The docs confirm that your approach is ok.

`base64.b64encode(byte_obj).decode('utf-8')` is correct - base64.b64encode [requires](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode) bytes as input:

> Encode the bytes-like object s using Base64 and return the encoded bytes.

However `base64.b64decode` [accepts](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64decode) bytes or an ascii string:

> Decode the Base64 encoded bytes-like object or ASCII string *s* and return the decoded bytes.

Comment: Thank you.  But when I use eg `...decode('latin-1')` I still get the same result.  So assuming everything else I do is correct, the question that remains is whether using `decode('utf-8')` is the correct approach for serialising the base64 encoded bytes to "str".

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use 'utf-8' or `latin-1` because both encodings encode ascii characters to the same values, and base64 only uses ascii.  So either is fine.