# Removing a string wrapper around pickled object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, pickle

In the following code:

```
>>> import pickle
>>>
>>> class Thing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "stackoverflow"
        self.age = 11

>>> a = pickle.dumps(Thing())
>>> a
b'\x80\x03c__main__\nThing\nq\x00)\x81q\x01}q\x02(X\x04\x00\x00\x00nameq\x03X\r\x00\x00\x00stackoverflowq\x04X\x03\x00\x00\x00ageq\x05K\x0bub.'
>>> str(a)
"b'\\x80\\x03c__main__\\nThing\\nq\\x00)\\x81q\\x01}q\\x02(X\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00nameq\\x03X\\r\\x00\\x00\\x00stackoverflowq\\x04X\\x03\\x00\\x00\\x00ageq\\x05K\\x0bub.'"
```

My question is, how do I convert `str(a)` back to `a`, since once that conversion happens I can easily decode using `pickle.loads()`

The reason that I am converting to string is that I wish to add `str(a)` string to another string that will be further "pickled." Most of the other posts I have seen assume that the bytes are already an encoding of a string or string to byte conversion, none of which this is.

Comment: Just keep `a` around and don't assign anything else to it then you can use it later.

Comment: You probably can't add another string to a pickled object string safely. What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work because arbitrary binary strings are valid `latin1` which can always be decoded to Unicode and then encoded back to the original string again (as pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22621777/355230) by [Sven Marnach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279627/sven-marnach)).

```
import pickle

class Thing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "stackoverflow"
        self.age = 11

a = pickle.dumps(Thing())
str_a = a.decode('latin1')    
b = str_a.encode('latin1')

assert a == b
```