# Read zip file in python3 same like python2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, unicode, byte

I save below code in 1 file. lets say `read_zipfile.py`.

```
with open("demo.zip", "rb") as f:
    read_data = f.read()
    print (read_data)
```

**python2 giving below output:**

```
[harsha@os]$ python2 read_zipfile.py
PK�flNdemo/PK
�flN����demo/hello.txtThi is Hello file
PK
�KK
   demo/hi.txtPK?�flN$��Ademo/
 �m@Q���^;T����m@Q���PK?
�flN����$ ���#demo/hello.txt
 �m@Q����m@Q����m@Q���PK?
�KK
   $ ���ademo/hi.txt
 ���B�������,���PK�
```

---

**python3 giving below output:**

```
[harsha@os]$ python3 read_zipfile.py
    b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x88flN\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00demo/PK\x03\x04\n\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x88flN\x83\x9d\xd9\xc9\x12\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x00demo/hello.txtThi is Hello file\nPK\x03\x04\n\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0\x18KK\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00demo/hi.txtPK\x01\x02?\x03\x14\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x88flN\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00$\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x80\xedA\x00\x00\x00\x00demo/\n\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x00\x80m@Q\xa4\xd8\xd4\x01\x00^;T\xa4\xd8\xd4\x01\x80m@Q\xa4\xd8\xd4\x01PK\x01\x02?\x03\n\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x88flN\x83\x9d\xd9\xc9\x12\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00$\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x80\xa4\x81#\x00\x00\x00demo/hello.txt\n\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x00\x80m@Q\xa4\xd8\xd4\x01\x80m@Q\xa4\xd8\xd4\x01\x80m@Q\xa4\xd8\xd4\x01PK\x01\x02?\x03\n\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0\x18KK\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00$\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x80\xa4\x81a\x00\x00\x00demo/hi.txt\n\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x00\x00\xb6\x96\xfa\x0fB\xd3\x01\x80\xd0\xd6\x16\xa4\xd8\xd4\x01\x00,\x17\x0f\xa4\xd8\xd4\x01PK\x05\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x03\x00\x14\x01\x00\x00\x8a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

**How can I get python2 output format using python3?**

Comment: That is exactly the same data, it's just printed differently. What's your goal here? Why are you printing the binary representation of a zip file?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I want data to be print like python2 in python3

Comment: @Aran-Fey : Can I convert python3 output in python2 format?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Python3 giving me in byte format. I want python2 output using python3.

Comment: Harsha Biyani: Why are you printing the binary data in a `.zip` file anyway?

Comment: @martineau Actually, we have an API to call and pass this binary data. Using Python2, API is working fine, but Python3 giving an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python3,  f.read() returns a bytes,
you should choose a encoding such as utf-8 and convert it to str.

Then it will be print like python2.

```
with open("demo.zip", "rb") as f:
    read_data = f.read()
    #print (read_data) 
    s = read_data.decode('latin1')
    print(s)
```

Comment: I tried this. This not giving me in the same format like Python2 output

Comment: it depends on , what is the actually decode your console use,    it maybe not utf-8

Comment: @martineau : Thanks a lo for your help. `latin1` helped me to solve the problem. Could you please add the answer? so that I can accept the same.

Comment: @Harsha Biyani: That's not necessary. I suggest you accept this one which contains the essence of the answer.

Comment: @martineau : Sure.. :)

Comment: @HarshaBiyani: BTW, using the `latin1` encoding to store binary data is kind of a "trick" in Python 3. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621143/serializing-binary-data-in-python/22621777#22621777) to a related related question.

Answer (score 0):

In order to dump raw bytes to STDOUT in Python 3, use the binary stream underlying `sys.stdout`.
It's accessible as the `.buffer` attribute.

Change `print(read_data)` to

```
sys.stdout.buffer.write(read_data)
sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'\n')
```

The last line is necessary if you want to exactly mimic what `print` does.