# When UTF is multibyte & latin1 is single byte, why do I get error?

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, utf-8

I am reading a CSV file, through pandas.read_csv(). When specifying enconding = UTF-8 or 16, it gives an error.

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 127: invalid start byte

My doubt is, when UTF is a multibyte encoding and latin1 is a single byte encoding, why do I get an error when using UTF-8 or 16, but works fine with latin1?
Shouldn't UTF be superior and decode all characters?

Thanks in advance.

Tried encoding = latin1, 'cp1252', 'iso-8859-15'

Comment: Not every random combination of bytes is valid in UTF-\*, but any random byte is valid in Latin-1.

Answer (score 6):

UTF-8 is self-synchronizing; you can tell where you are in a multibyte character without examining the neighboring characters. So if you reach a byte that isn't a start byte before hitting a start byte, you know it's either not UTF-8, or the UTF-8 is corrupt.

UTF-8 isn't magic; you can *encode* just about anything to UTF-8, but you can only *decode* as UTF-8 when you have UTF-8 bytes.

Latin-1 decodes everything because latin-1, like most one byte per character ASCII superset encodings, is dumb. It just maps every byte value to a single character (the equivalent Unicode ordinal in the case of latin-1). So no matter what garbage you throw at it, latin-1 will decode it, but the result will also be garbage unless the text actually *is* latin-1 (or ASCII, which latin-1 is a superset of). This is why the one byte per character ASCII supersets are generally a bad idea; if you use the Windows locale's chosen ASCII superset, then it works on your machine and that of anyone else with the same locale, but as soon as it is loaded on a machine in a different locale, they silently get garbage.

Short answer: Your data isn't UTF-8 encoded, or it's corrupted. [You need to figure out what it really is](https://www.google.com/search?q=identify+text+encoding).

Comment: Wow! Thanks. That gave a lot of clarity.

Comment: And fundamental to computerized text, you _should_ only decode as X when you have X bytes.