# Memory error in deserializing small gzip file

Tags: python, serialization, gzip

i have 30 gzip files needed to be de-serialized .i used following code as de-serializing code :

```
def deserialize(f):
    retval = {}
    while True:
        content = f.read(struct.calcsize('L'))
        if not content: break
        k_len = struct.unpack('L', content)[0]
        k_bstr = f.read(k_len)
        k = k_bstr.decode('utf-8')
        v_len = struct.unpack('L', f.read(struct.calcsize('L')))[0]
        v_bytes = os.io.BytesIO(f.read(v_len))
        v = numpy.load(v_bytes, allow_pickle=True)
        retval[k] = v.item()
    return retval


for i in range(0,26):

    with gzip.open('Files/company'+str(i)+'.zip','rb') as f:
        curdic1 = deserialize(f)
    n = 0
    for key in curdic1:
        n = n + 1
        company = curdic1[key]
        if (n % 10000 == 1):
            print(i, key)
```

but when it gives me following exception during deserializing:

> k_bstr = f.read(k_len)
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.5/gzip.py", line 274, in read
>       return self._buffer.read(size)
>   MemoryError

in addition, each file's size is less than 4 mb!. so what is the problem with this code?

Edited:
[sample file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=06905299573733582284)]

**Edited**
this is serialize method if can help to clarify ...:

```
def serialize(f, content):
    for k,v in content.items():
        # write length of key, followed by key as string
        k_bstr = k.encode('utf-8')
        f.write(struct.pack('L', len(k_bstr)))
        f.write(k_bstr)
        # write length of value, followed by value in numpy.save format
        memfile = io.BytesIO()
        numpy.save(memfile, v)
        f.write(struct.pack('L', memfile.tell()))
        f.write(memfile.getvalue())
```

Comment: Probably unrelated to your problem, but the filenames suggest `zip` compression (requiring the `zipfile` module rather than `gzip`).

Comment: @Seb no its not the problem

Comment: Put in an `assert` sanity check after reading `k_len`. Maybe the input file is corrupt.

Comment: @martineau can u explain more?

Comment: `assert klen <= reasonable_upper_limit`

Comment: @martineau k_len is "3472330498737438728"

Comment: @martineau the problem is i dont know how can i read this file line by line and decode with utf-8 . one line can not conevrt to utf-8

Comment: I have no idea what's in (or at least supposed to be in) the gzip file, so it's impossible to help. If you add a description of that to your question as well as a link to a small test file, then that maybe someone can help you further.

Comment: @martineau ok i will attach a file

Comment: I need a description of what's in the file. Is it just a gzipped text file? If not, please [edit] your question and add that information (not just the file).

Comment: @martineau its a dictionary structure

Comment: You can't store Python dictionaries directly in a file, so there must be more to it. Is it a gzipped `pickle` of a dictionary or something else.

Comment: @martineau i am not sure its a dictionary !

Comment: You seem to have some notion of what's in the file. How is it being created? Knowing what you're dealing with is crucial especially if you're having problems—like right now.

Comment: @martineau i guss what is it but its not the problem the problem is in this line:k_bstr = f.read(k_len).  it seems k_bstr can not save a string with k_len=3472330498737438728! i dont know how should i handle that

Comment: @martineau i add serialize method to clarify

Comment: Instead of `'utf-8'`, try using `'latin1'` when serializing and de-serializing. This is the proper way to handle binary data. See [Serializing binary data in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621143/serializing-binary-data-in-python/22621777#22621777)

Comment: @martineau i dont have access to data previous the serialized. if i had this i never used deserialization .and my data is in persian language i cant serialize the data with latin1

Comment: The `struct` module is generally used for read and writing binary data, so using it to read text encoded in utf-8 is weird.

Comment: I think the problem is your `deserialize()` function isn't reading what the `serialize()` function produces properly. My advice is work on standalone code that does nothing but round-trip (write and then read back) the data properly.

Comment: @martineau you mean this data did not serialized with this serialize code?

Comment: No, I meant the `deserialize()` function isn't properly doing what it is supposed to do (independent from the fact that the data is getting gzipped). So work on just getting that part working in isolation. Specifically I don't think the `serialize()` function is writing what `deserialize()` reads in as `content` — in other words what being written doesn't match what is being read which could cause the problem you're seeing.

Comment: The `serialize` function does produce output that can be read with this `deserialize` function. The problem is that the gzip files were produced on a 32-bit machine with a different size of `L`, so the data structure doesn't match up. Explicitly specifying `<L` to match the original platform fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inspected your sample file and found that the length fields were not encoded as `L` but as `<L`. My guess is that they were serialised on a 32-bit platform were the native length of `L` is equal to the standard value of 4 bytes, whereas you are running the deserialising function on a 64-bit platform where the native length of `L` is 8 bytes. So the function should be:

```py
import struct, io
import numpy as np

def deserialize(f):
    retval = {}
    while True:
        content = f.read(struct.calcsize('<L'))
        if not content: break
        k_len = struct.unpack('<L', content)[0]
        k_bstr = f.read(k_len)
        k = k_bstr.decode('utf-8')
        v_len = struct.unpack('<L', f.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
        v_bytes = io.BytesIO(f.read(v_len))
        v = np.load(v_bytes, allow_pickle=True)
        retval[k] = v.item()
    return retval
```

Part of the deserialised output of your sample file:

```py
{'12000001': {'NID': '',
  'companyid': '12000001',
  'newspaperdate': '۱۳۸۵/۶/۲۰',
  'indikatornumber': '۱۸۹۶۲',
  'newsdate': None,
  'newstitle': 'آگهی تاسیس شرکت فنی مهندسی آریا\u200cپژوه گرمسار (سهامی خاص)',
  'persons': [],
  'subjects': ['انجام',
   'کلیه',
   'خدمات',
   'ترویج',
   'آموزش',
   [...]
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro! :) You've made my day! I was stuck in this code for hours!