# How to deal with TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, serialization, base64

Trying to convert output into Json format but getting the error. After removing the json.dump getting the data into base64 format. But when using json.dump it shows error.

Code:

```
import json 
import base64

with open(r"C:/Users/Documents/pdf2txt/outputImage.jpg","rb") as img:
    image = base64.b64encode(img.read())
    data['ProcessedImage'] = image

print(json.dump(data)
```

Output:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable
```

When using:

```
print(json.dumps(dict(data)))
```

It's also showing the same error

Comment: Ensure to post *valid* code which results in the behavior described. The code shown will fail to parse / run, for at least two separate reasons. Without *valid* code which reproduces the issue described, one sometimes correct hypothesis, is that the actual problematic code and shown code differ.

Comment: You're getting the same error because it has nothing to do with what you are using in the `print` function call — it's from the `image = base64.b64encode(img.read())` line.

Answer (score 7):

**You have to use the [str.decode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) method.**

You are trying to serialize a object of type bytes to a JSON object.
There is no such thing in the [JSON schema](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation). So you have to convert the bytes to a String first.

Also you should use [json.dumps()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) instead of json.dump() because you dont want to write to a File.

In your example:

```
import json 
import base64

with open(r"C:/Users/Documents/pdf2txt/outputImage.jpg", "rb") as img:
    image = base64.b64encode(img.read())
    data['ProcessedImage'] = image.decode() # not just image

print(json.dumps(data))
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, I think you should use `json.dumps()` because you're calling `json.dump()` with the incorrect arguments and it doesn't return anything to print.

Secondly, as the error message indicates, you can't serializable objects of type `bytes` which is what `json.dumps()` expects. To do this properly you need to decode the binary data into a Python string with some encoding. To preserve the data properly, you should use `latin1` encoding because arbitrary binary strings *are* valid `latin1` which can always be decoded to Unicode and then encoded back to the original string again (as pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22621777/355230) by [Sven Marnach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279627/sven-marnach)).

Here's your code showing how to do that (plus corrections for the other not-directly-related problems it had):

```
import json
import base64

image_path = "C:/Users/Documents/pdf2txt/outputImage.jpg"
data = {}

with open(image_path, "rb") as img:
    image = base64.b64encode(img.read()).decode('latin1')
    data['ProcessedImage'] = image

print(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: Still having the same issue getting the print output in the form of bs64 encoded , as i am new to this can you please show me how to get the real output as how to decode bs64 to get the real data . Thanks in advance .

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking. You can undo the decoding of the value and get the `bytes` back with `image.encode('latin1')`.

Answer (score 2):

`image` (or anythong returned by `base64.b64encode`) is a binary `bytes` object, not a string. JSON cannot deal with binary data. You must decode the image data if you want to serialize it:

```
data['ProcessedImage'] = image.decode()
```

Comment: How to get the real data from bs64 encoded value , how i can decode it to get the actual value .