# In Python, is there a way to use json.dumps on an object that uses __slots__?

Tags: python, json, cpython

When I try to use `json.dumps` on an object of a class that uses `__slots__`, I get "...is not JSON serializable," or possibly an `AttributeError` that `__dict__` is missing. How can I get this to work? It seems that `__slots__` should tell the interpreter to use a virtual dictionary for compatibility.

```
import json

class Foo:
     __slots__ = ["bar"]
     def __init__(self):
         self.bar = 0

json.dumps(Foo())
```

Comment: You cannot do this on objects *without* `__slots__` either. What makes you think it would work on other objects?

Comment: You might find the question [_Making object JSON serializable with regular encoder_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478287/making-object-json-serializable-with-regular-encoder) helpful.

Comment: You need to use `pickle` if you want to serialize an object.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It looks like I was *actually* doing `json.dumps(Foo(), default=lambda o: o.__dict__)`, but I forgot that when writing my question.

Comment: @Vor: I need a serialization that will work outside Python and is human-readable. `pickle` won't work outside Python, and even has issues within Python if class definitions change.

Comment: @Vor: no, pickle is but one option. JSON just takes some more work.

Answer (score 3):

Plain, vanilla `json.dumps()` doesn't support custom classes, period. It doesn't matter if they use `__slots__` or not here.

A popular way to handle custom classes is to use a hook that returns their `__dict__` attribute instead, and that obviously won't work here. You'd have to find another way to serialise such objects.

One way would be for such objects to have a dedicated method:

```
class Foo:
     __slots__ = ["bar"]
     def __init__(self):
         self.bar = 0

     def json_serialize(self):
         return {'bar': self.bar}
```

and use that in your `default` hook:

```
json.dumps(Foo(), default=lambda o: o.json_serialize())
```