# Python TCP trying to send object a bytes-like object is required

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to send a custom object via sockets in Python. My object is defined as:

```
packet = Packet.Packet(MAGIC_NUMBER,0,sender_next,packet_size,local_buffer)
port_out.send(packet)
```

But I am getting an error of: 
*builtins.TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Packet'*

I've seen previous posts about using .encode() for str types but how do I do it for a custom object like this? Do I need to make a encode method?

Comment: You need a way of converting to `bytes`. For strings that is `.encode()`. For your `Packet` object it's whatever you choose to call it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to send objects through python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27542447/how-to-send-objects-through-python)

Comment: How do I create this .encode() function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pickle

```
import pickle

packet = Packet.Packet(MAGIC_NUMBER,0,sender_next,packet_size,local_buffer)
port_out.send(pickle.dumps(packet))
```

https://pymotw.com/3/pickle/index.html