# Python3.5 object and json.dumps() output

Tags: python, json, class, datetime, python-3.5

I wrote a class that would allow me to add days (integers) to dates (string %Y-%m-%d). The objects of this class need to be JSON serializable.

Adding days in the form of integers to my objects works as expected. However json.dumps(obj) returns too much info ("2016-03-23 15:57:47.926362") for my original object. **Why ?** How would I need to modify the class to get ""2016-03-23" instead ? Please see the example below.

**Code:**

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import json

class Day(str):
    def __init__(self, _datetime):
        self.day = _datetime

    def __str__(self):
        return self.day.date().isoformat()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s" % self.day.date().isoformat()

    def __add__(self, day):
        new_day = self.day + timedelta(days=day)
        return Day(new_day).__str__()

    def __sub__(self, day):
        new_day = self.day - timedelta(days=day)
        return Day(new_day).__str__()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    today = Day(datetime.today())
    print(today)               # 2016-03-23
    print(json.dumps(today))   # "2016-03-23 15:57:47.926362"
    print(today+1)             # 2016-03-24
    print(json.dumps(today+1)) # "2016-03-24"
    print(today-1)             # 2016-03-22
    print(json.dumps(today-1)) # "2016-03-22"
```

---

**Update**. Here's my final code for those interested:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import json


class Day(str):
    def __init__(self, datetime_obj):
        self.day = datetime_obj

    def __new__(self, datetime):
        return str.__new__(Day, datetime.date().isoformat())

    def __add__(self, day):
        new_day = self.day + timedelta(days=day)
        return Day(new_day)

    def __sub__(self, day):
        new_day = self.day - timedelta(days=day)
        return Day(new_day)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    today = Day(datetime.today())
    print(type(today))
    print(today)  # 2016-03-23
    print(json.dumps(today))  # "2016-03-23"
    print(today + 1)  # 2016-03-24
    print(json.dumps(today + 1))  # "2016-03-24"
    print(today - 1)  # 2016-03-22
    print(json.dumps(today - 1))  # "2016-03-22"
    print(json.dumps(dict(today=today))) # {"today": "2016-03-23"}
    print(json.dumps(dict(next_year=today+365))) # {"next_year": "2017-03-23"}
    print(json.dumps(dict(last_year=today-366))) # {"last_year": "2015-03-23"}
```

Comment: Note that your results would be more consistent if you removed the `.__str__()` from `__add__` and `__sub__`.

Comment: True. But how could I remove time from my result ?

Comment: unrelated: 1- you should remove `__str__()` from `__add__`, `__sub__` (e.g., to support `today + 1 + 1`) 2- don't override `str.__str__`, override `str.__new__` to customize the string representation instead.

Comment: That's what I did in the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cool! Let's go with it. You are seeing:

```
print(json.dumps(today))   # "2016-03-23 15:57:47.926362"
```

Because [somewhere](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/json/encoder.py) in the encoding process, when deciding how to serialize what was passed to it, `json.dumps` calls `isinstance(..., str)` on your object. This returns `True` and your object is serialized like this string it secretly is.

But where does the `"2016-03-23 15:57:47.926362"` value come from?

When you call `day = Day(datetime_obj)`, two things happen:

- `__new__` [is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init) to *instantiate* the object. You haven't provided a `__new__` method, so `str.__new__` is used.
- `__init__` is called to *initialize* the object.

So `day = Day(datetime_obj)` effectively translates to:

```
day = str.__new__(Day, datetime_obj)
```

For `json.dumps`, your object will be a `str`, but the value of the `str` is set to the default string representation of `datetime_obj`. Which happens to be the full format you are seeing. Builtins, man!

I played around with this, and it seems if you roll your own `__new__` (which is slightly exciting territory, tread carefully) which intercepts the `str.__new__` call, you ~~should~~ be fine:

```
class Day(str):
    def __new__(self, datetime):
        return str.__new__(Day, datetime.date().isoformat())
```

But you didn't hear it from me if the whole thing catches fire.

**PS** The proper way [would be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478287/making-object-json-serializable-with-regular-encoder) to subclass `JSONEncoder`. But there is zero fun in it.

**PS2** Oh, shoot, I tested this on `2.7`. I may be completely out there, and if I am, just give me a ["you tried"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyNjO.png) badge.

Comment: You're a star! I did experiment with __new__ but without much luck. You had one mistake in the suggested code, which I edited. Your answer is indeed a great explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the `json.dumps(today)`'s behavior is not as obvious as it might appear at the first glance. To understand the issue, you should be able to answer two questions:

- where does the string value that includes the time come from?
- why `Day.__str__` is not called by json encoder ? Should it?

Here're some prerequisites:

1. `datetime.today()` method is similar to `datetime.now()` -- it includes the current time (hour, minutes, etc). You could **use `date.today()`, to get only date.**
2. `str` creates immutable objects in Python; its value is set in the `__new__` method that you have not overriden and therefore the default conversion `str(datetime.today())` is used  to initialize `Day`'s value as a string. It creates the string value that includes both date and time in your case. You could **override `__new__`, to get a different string value**:

   ```
   def __new__(cls, _datetime):
       return str.__new__(cls, _datetime.date())
   ```
3. `Day` is a `str` subclass and therefore its instances are encoded as JSON strings
4. `str` methods return `str` objects instead of the corresponding subclass objects unless you override them e.g.:

   ```
   >>> class S(str):
   ...    def duplicate(self):
   ...        return S(self * 2)
   ...
   >>> s = S('abc')
   >>> s.duplicate().duplicate()
   'abcabcabcabc'
   >>> s.upper().duplicate()
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'duplicate'
   ```

   `s.upper()` returns `str` object instead of `S` here and the following `.duplicate()` call fails.

In your case, to create the corresponding JSON string, `json.dumps(today)` performs an operation (`re.sub()` call in `json.encode.encode_basestring()`) on the `today` object that uses its value as a string i.e., the issue is that neither `re.sub()` nor `encode_basestring()` call `__str__()` method on instances of `str` subclasses. Even if `encode_basestring(s)` were as simple as `return '"' + s + '"'`; the result would be the same: `'"' + today` returns a `str` object and `Day.__str__` is not called.

I don't know whether `re` module should call `str(obj)` in functions that accept `isinstance(obj, str)`. Or whether `json.encode.encode_basestring()` should do it (or neither).

If you can't fix `Day` class; you could **patch `json.encode.encode_basestring()` to call `str(obj)`, to get a desirable  JSON representation for `str` subtype instances** (***if*** you want to get the value returned by `__str__()` method -- *putting aside whether it is wise to override `__str__()` on a `str` subclass in the first place*):

```
import json

for suffix in ['', '_ascii']:
    function_name = 'encode_basestring' + suffix
    orig_function = getattr(json.encoder, function_name)
    setattr(json.encoder, function_name, lambda s,_e=orig_function: _e(str(s)))
```

Related Python issue: [Cannot override JSON encoding of basic type subclasses](http://bugs.python.org/issue12657)