# How to deserialise enumeration with string representation?

Tags: python, serialization, enums, json-deserialization, python-attrs

I would like to create a class, which has an enumeration as an attribute.
This enumeration should have a string representation that shows up as human-readable value when dumping the instance of the class that uses the enum attribute as a JSON string.
In the minimal working example below, I created three enumerations in three different ways.

After the deserialization, each attribute shows us that it comes from an enumeration except the enumeration with a string representation. It is just a string.

If it is not possible to realize such a structure, I would like to know why.

### Requirements

If you would like to test it, you have to install `jsons` and `attrs` with

```sh
pip install attrs jsons
```

### Minimal working example

Here you see a minimal working example.

```py
import jsons
import attr

from enum import Enum

# ----------------------------------------------------
# create enumeration with the help of a dictionary

fruits = {
    "PINEAPPLE": "PINEAPPLE",
    "APPLE": "APPLE",
    "ORANGE": "ORANGE",
    "BANANA": "BANANA",
}

Fruit = Enum("FRUITS", fruits)

# ----------------------------------------------------
# create a classical enumeration


class Nut(Enum):

    PEANUT = 1
    HAZELNUT = 2
    CASHEW = 3
    WALNUT = 4


# ----------------------------------------------------
# create enumeration with a string representation


class Vegetable(str, Enum):

    BROCCOLI = "BROCCOLI"
    CUCUMBER = "CUCUMBER"
    POTATO = "POTATO"
    ONION = "ONION"


# ----------------------------------------------------
# create a class which uses the enumerations


@attr.s(auto_attribs=True, kw_only=True)
class Order(jsons.JsonSerializable):
    fruit: Fruit
    nut: Nut
    vegetable: Vegetable


# ----------------------------------------------------
# initialize an order object, serialize and deserialize it

order = Order(fruit=Fruit.APPLE, nut=Nut.PEANUT, vegetable=Vegetable.CUCUMBER)

json_string: str = Order.dumps(order)

order_deserialised: Order = Order.loads(json_string)
```

Structure of the `order` and `order_deserialised` variable:

```
order:              Order(fruit=<FRUITS.APPLE: 'APPLE'>, nut=<Nut.PEANUT: 1>, vegetable=<Vegetable.CUCUMBER: 'CUCUMBER'>)

order_deserialised: Order(fruit=<FRUITS.APPLE: 'APPLE'>, nut=<Nut.PEANUT: 1>, vegetable='CUCUMBER')
```

As you can see, the `order_deserialised` shows the vegetable as a string and not an enumeration.

Comment: Why are you inheriting from `str`???  `class Vegetable(str, Enum):`? This is likely throwing off the `attrs`/`jsons` libraries, somewhere I suspect, there is some check `isinstance(x, str)`, and it isn't handling `str` subtypes.... "create enumeration with a string representation" That isn't a reasonable way of doing this. Just write a `__str__` and a `__repr__` method. Inheriting from `str` seems to be your issue. Your enumeration *is a string*, that is what inheriting from `str` does, so it's not surprising that it is being treated as one.

Comment: Fundamentally, it isn't clear what you mean by "create an enumeration with a string reprsentation", *what is it you are tryin to achieve by inheriting from `str`*?

Comment: Yeah you are both right. I saw this structure on [another stack overflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58608361/string-based-enum-in-python/58608362#58608362)
I stick to the dictionary ansatz. Thanks for your help =)

Comment: Or of course, you can just *not* inherit from `str`, so `class Vegetable(Enum): ...`

Comment: This enumeration is an attribute of a class which will be serialised into a JSON file. There I would like to see the value and not only the number. Or is there also another option to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean, "the value, not only the number", *what number*? In any case, your library almost certainly allows you to control the serialization any way you want. Having an `enum` type inherit from `str` **defeats the whole purpose of `enum`** in the same way as having it inherit from `int`. I re-opened the question, because I don't think the duplicate was a great fit.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you already know this, but I am answering for future readers.

This problem was fixed in JSONS 1.6.1, as you can see in the following example.

```
import enum
import jsons

class Vegetable(str, enum.Enum):
    BROCCOLI = "BROCCOLI"

print(jsons.loads(jsons.dumps(Vegetable.BROCCOLI), Vegetable))
# This will output "Vegetable.BROCCOLI" with JSONS 1.6.1 or later
```

And deriving a class like `class Vegetable(str, Enum)` is perfectly fine, unlike what others commented on the question. A similar idea was added as the [`StrEnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.StrEnum) in Python 3.11.