# encode Pydantic field using the Enum name instead of the value

Tags: python, enums, model, pydantic

I have a Enum class:

```py
class Group(enum.Enum):
    user = 0
    manager = 1
    admin = 2
```

I have a pydantic model:

```py
class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    username: str
    group: Group
```

It generated serialised to json following:

```json
{
    "id": 5,
    "username": "admin",
    "group": 2
}
```

However, I would like to get the name of the enum field instead of its value, so it should be:

```json
{
    "id": 5,
    "username": "admin",
    "group": "admin"
}
```

Is this possible at all? If so, how?

Comment: For clues on serializing/deserializing via JSON start here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36709785/208880

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not trying to "load" anything, your problem is that you want to **encode** your Pydantic field using the **Enum name** instead of the value, when **serialising** your model to JSON.

All you need to do is add a `Config` class to your `BaseModel` subclass that specifies a JSON encoder for the `Group` type. The `json_encoders` attribute is a `dict` keyed on type with serialiser callables:

```
import enum
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Group(enum.Enum):
    user = 0
    manager = 1
    admin = 2


class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    username: str
    group: Group

    class Config:
        json_encoders = {Group: lambda g: g.name}


user = User(id=5, username="admin", group=2)
print(user)  # id=5 username='admin' group=<Group.admin: 2>
print(user.json())  # {"id": 5, "username": "admin", "group": "admin"}
```

Comment: For others who may want to go further, and actually *validate* their Enum by name, that is to *create* the `BaseModel` using Enum names instead of values, try this: https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/2980

Comment: There is also this question that tackles customised Enums including modifying the schema and validating input by name instead of value - *and* the Enum is loaded dynamically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75587442/validate-pydantic-dynamic-float-enum-by-name-with-openapi-description

Answer (score 7):

The method given in the accepted answer has been deprecated for Pydantic V2.  The V2 method is to use [custom serializer decorators](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/serialization/#custom-serializers), so the way to do this would now look like so:

```py
import enum
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_serializer


class Group(enum.Enum):
    user = 0
    manager = 1
    admin = 2


class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    username: str
    group: Group

    @field_serializer("group")
    def serialize_group(self, group: Group, _info):
        return group.name
```

Comment: Nice. Many of the other answers apply the enum names instead of values for all fields in the model (or all invocations of the enum). This method allows per-field control, such that a model could have one field that uses the enum values and another that uses the enum names.

Comment: I just tried this approach to generate a clean OpenAPI documentation with FastAPI for a route response model... and it does not work (yet?) Pydantic v2.4.2, FastAPI 0.103.0.

Comment: Maybe there is something in the way FastAPI does the JSON conversion that doesn't quite work.  I use the `model_dump_json` method of `BaseModel` directly and have had no problems (Pydantic v2.4.1).

Answer (score 3):

In 2.5 this is simple using the `PlainSerializer`.

[Relevant Docs](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.5/concepts/serialization/)

```py
import pydantic, enum
from typing import Annotated

EnumNameSerializer = pydantic.PlainSerializer(
    lambda e: e.name,
    return_type='str',
    when_used='always')

class Group(enum.Enum):
    user = 0
    manager = 1
    admin = 2

class User(pydantic.BaseModel):
    id: int
    username: str
    group: Annotated[Group, EnumNameSerializer]

print(User(group=Group.admin, id=0, username='admin_user').model_dump_json())

>>> {"id":0,"username":"admin_user","group":"admin"}
```

Note the change of type for the `group` attribute:

```
group: Annotated[Group, EnumNameSerializer]
```

Since this uses `when_used='always'`, this will also output the enum name when exporting to a dict with `.model_dump()`

Answer (score 1):

You could override the dunder method **repr** in the Enum class in this way:

```
class Group(enum.Enum):
    user = 0
    manager = 1
    admin = 2

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76233530/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In the `pydantic` Github I found a discussion tackling this issue: [Map string value to int #598](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/598)

samuelcolvin suggested this:

```
class Choices(int, Enum):
    anne = 1
    ben = 2
    charlie = 3
    dave = 4

    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        cls.lookup = {v: k.value for v, k in cls.__members__.items()}
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v):
        try:
            return cls.lookup[v]
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError('invalid value')

class Model(BaseModel):
    choice: Choices

debug(Model(choice='charlie'))
```

Comment: this doesnt work.

Comment: It works with `pydantic==1.10.6`, I tested it. Maybe there are problems with pydantic v2?

Answer (score 0):

Not answering the question directly, but it's related.

If you want to bind an enum to a pydantic model without relying on its `value`, you can create an enum on the fly. (Python >= 3.11) This works with FastAPI and the generated OpenAPI schema will reflect it properly.

```py
class Group(Enum):
    user = 0
    manager = 1
    admin = 2


group_enum_names = Enum("GroupEnumNames", [(g.name, g.name) for g in Group])


class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    username: str
    group: group_enum_names


# works
print(User(**{"id": 5, "username": "admin", "group": "admin"}))
# yields {"id":5,"username":"admin","group":"admin"}

# does not work, there are no ties to the original enum anymore
print(User(**{"id": 5, "username": "admin", "group": 1}))
# yields pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError
```

And to map back to the original `Group` enum:

```py
user = User(**{"id": 5, "username": "admin", "group": "admin"})
group = Group[user.group.name]
```

Arguably, some logic to could be added directly into the `User` model to handle that.

Note: mypy 1.6.1 does not like that solution and yields `Second argument of Enum() must be string, tuple, list or dict literal for mypy to determine Enum members [misc]` over the dynamically created enum, even if the second argument is a tuple.

Tested with:

- pydantic v2.4.2
- fastapi v0.103.0

Answer (score -1):

```py
class Group(enum.Enum):
    user = "user"
    manager = "manager"
    admin = "admin"
```

did the trick :o

Comment: Do you need to deserialize that back from JSON to Python?  How would you do it?

Comment: Hopefully the OP can add a complete example showing pydantic both serializing and unserializing some data.

Comment: No, its done by fastapi ... I do not serialize by myself.