# python json object array not serializable

Tags: python, json, ajax, serialization

I have a class and array in a loop. I'm filling the object and appending it to the array. How do I pass array data to web side through JSON? I have an error that says JSON  is not serializable. How can I serialize to a JSON?

```
class myclass(object):
    def __init__(self,vehicle,mng01):
        self.vehicle = vehicle
        self.vehicle = vehicle

#--Main function--
@subApp.route('/jsontry', method=['POST'])
def data():
    for x in list:
        vehicle_sum.append(myclass( x,str(mng01))

    return json.dumps({'success':'1','vehicle':vehicle_sum})
```

Comment: what is mng01 can you give an example.

Comment: Can you post the error stack please ? When I try to dump `{'success':'1','vehicle':vehicle_sum}` with `vehicle_sum` being a standard python array, it works. Please provide more details regarding the error and the objects you use :)

Comment: @FloranGmehlin: It is a list, of instances of `myclass`. This will not work out of the box. See my answer below :)

Comment: I see, did not think about that :) Thx !

Comment: Why do you have two `self.vehicle = vehicle` statements in `myclass.__init__()`?

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18561055/355230) to a related question.

Answer (score 4):

Does it say myclass object is not JSON serializable? This is because there is no way for `json.dumps(..)` to know how to JSON-serialize your class. You will need to write your [custom encoder to do that](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder).

Below is a sample implementation. I am sure you can modify it for your use case.

```
import json

class Temp(object):
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

class CustomEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Temp):
            return {"num": obj.num}
        #Let the base class handle the problem.
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

obj = [Temp(42), Temp(42)]


print json.dumps(obj, cls=CustomEncoder)

#Output: [{"num": 42}, {"num": 42}]
```

---

If you don't want over-complicate stuff, here's what you can do:

```
all_vehicles = [{"vehicle": x.vehicle} for x in vehicle_sum]
json.dumps({'success':'1','vehicle':all_vehicles)
```

Comment: I get `An attribute defined in json.encoder line 162 hides this method `, it happens on the line `def default(self, obj):` but the code still works.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't say that JSON is not serializable, it says that your instances of `myclass` are not JSON serializable. I.e. they cannot be represented as JSON, because it is really not clear what do you expect as an output.

To find out how to make a class JSON serializable, check this question: [How to make a class JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable)

In this trivial case, depending on what exactly you're trying to achieve, you might be good with inserting `[x.vehicle for x in vehicle_sum]` in your JSON. If you really need to insert your instances data in JSON in a direct way, you'll have to write an encoder.