# How to send arbitrary objects with socket.send()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I have a very simple TCP server in Python 3.6, and I would like to use it to send arbitrary objects.

I am able to send a simple list with this code:

```
myList = [99, 88]
current_connection.send(bytes(myList))
```

However, this code fails with exception `'dict' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`.

```
myList = [99,88,{'a': 3},77]
current_connection.send(bytes(myList))
```

How can I send this `list`, which contains a `tuple`?

I would also like to send a custom object like this:

```
myObject = customObject()
current_connection.send(bytes(myObject))
```

However, that code throws exception `cannot convert 'customObject' object to bytes`. What is the proper way to send the custom object?

Is there a method I should be using other than socket.send()?

Here is the complete code:

```
import socket

def listen():
    connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    connection.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    connection.bind(('localhost', 5555))
    connection.listen(10)
    while True:
        current_connection, address = connection.accept()
        while True:
            data = current_connection.recv(2048)
            try:
                #myList = [99,88,{'a': 3},77]
                myList = [99, 88]
                current_connection.send(bytes(myList))
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            print(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        listen()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    print('done')
```

If `send()` cannot do what I have described, is there a more effective way to send data?

Comment: To send an arbitrary object over a socket, you need to *serialize* it to a stream of bytes.  The `pickle`, `json`, and `struct` modules are different approaches to this.

Comment: Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478287/making-object-json-serializable-with-regular-encoder/18561055#18561055) that shows how to convert them to JSON format which uses the `pickle` and `json` modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you convert your list to json first and transmit across socket like:

```
myList = [99,88,{'a': 3},77]
current_connection.send(json.dumps(myList).encode())
```

At receiver

```
myList = json.loads(received_bytes.decode())
```

> I would also like to send a custom object like this:

Two solution exists

1. easiest is pickle.dumps(your_obj).
2. Write json serializer for your object.

Comment: Both the JSON and the pickle solution worked in my case. To serialize an object to JSON, I used this: `json.dumps(c, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)`.