# JSON Serialization is empty when serialising from eulxml in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, pickle, exist-db

I am working with eXistDB in python and leveraging the `eulxml` library to handle mapping from the xml in the database into custom objects. I want to then serialize these objects to json (for another application to consume) but I'm running into issues. `jsonpickle` doesn't work (it ends up returning all sorts of excess garbage and the value are the fields aren't actually encoded but rather their eulxml type) and the standard `json.dumps()` is simply giving me empty json (this was after trying to implement the solution detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31742314/1313890)). The problem seems to stem from the fact that the `__dict__` values are not initialised `__oninit__` (as they are mapped as class properties) so the `__dict__` appears empty upon serialization. Here is some sample code:

**Serializable Class Object**

```
class Serializable(dict):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # hack to fix _json.so make_encoder serialize properly
        self.__setitem__('dummy', 1)

    def _myattrs(self):
        return [
            (x, self._repr(getattr(self, x)))
            for x in self.__dir__()
            if x not in Serializable().__dir__()
        ]

    def _repr(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, (str, int, float, list, tuple, dict)):
            return value
        else:
            return repr(value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<%s.%s object at %s>' % (
            self.__class__.__module__,
            self.__class__.__name__,
            hex(id(self))
        )

    def keys(self):
        return iter([x[0] for x in self._myattrs()])

    def values(self):
        return iter([x[1] for x in self._myattrs()])

    def items(self):
        return iter(self._myattrs())
```

**Base Class**

```
from eulxml import xmlmap
import inspect
import lxml
import json as JSON
from models.serializable import Serializable

class AlcalaBase(xmlmap.XmlObject,Serializable):

    def toJSON(self):
        return JSON.dumps(self, indent=4)

    def to_json(self, skipBegin=False):
        json = list()
        if not skipBegin:
            json.append('{')
        json.append(str.format('"{0}": {{', self.ROOT_NAME))
        for attr, value in inspect.getmembers(self):
            if (attr.find("_") == -1
                and attr.find("serialize") == -1
                and attr.find("context") == -1
                and attr.find("node") == -1
                and attr.find("schema") == -1):
                if type(value) is xmlmap.fields.NodeList:
                    if len(value) > 0:
                        json.append(str.format('"{0}": [', attr))
                        for v in value:
                            json.append(v.to_json())
                            json.append(",")
                        json = json[:-1]
                        json.append("]")
                    else:
                        json.append(str.format('"{0}": null', attr))
                elif (type(value) is xmlmap.fields.StringField
                        or type(value) is str
                        or type(value) is lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult):
                        value = JSON.dumps(value)
                        json.append(str.format('"{0}": {1}', attr, value))
                elif (type(value) is xmlmap.fields.IntegerField
                    or type(value) is int
                    or type(value) is float):
                    json.append(str.format('"{0}": {1}', attr, value))
                elif value is None:
                    json.append(str.format('"{0}": null', attr))
                elif type(value) is list:
                    if len(value) > 0:
                        json.append(str.format('"{0}": [', attr))
                        for x in value:
                            json.append(x)
                            json.append(",")
                        json = json[:-1]
                        json.append("]")
                    else:
                        json.append(str.format('"{0}": null', attr))
                else:
                    json.append(value.to_json(skipBegin=True))
                json.append(",")
        json = json[:-1]
        if not skipBegin:
            json.append('}')
        json.append('}')
        return ''.join(json)
```

**Sample Class that implements Base**

```
from eulxml import xmlmap
from models.alcalaMonth import AlcalaMonth
from models.alcalaBase import AlcalaBase

class AlcalaPage(AlcalaBase):
    ROOT_NAME = "page"
    id = xmlmap.StringField('pageID')
    year = xmlmap.IntegerField('content/@yearID')
    months = xmlmap.NodeListField('content/month', AlcalaMonth)
```

The `toJSON()` method on the base is the method that is using the `Serializable` class and is returning empty json, e.g. "{}". The `to_json()` is my attempt to for a json-like implementation but that has it's own problems (for some reason it skips certain properties / child objects for no reason I can see but thats a thread for another day).

If I attempt to access `myobj.keys` or `myobj.values` (both of which are exposed via `Serializable`) I can see property names and values as I would expect but I have no idea why json.dumps() produces an empty json string.

Does anyone have any idea why I cannot get these objects to serialize to json?! I've been pulling my hair out for weeks with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not familiar with eulxml, but I wonder if this XML-to-JSON conversion is necessary, since eXist is natively capable of serializing data as JSON. With XQuery 3.1, JSON serialization is a built-in feature of the language.

Comment: Hi @joewiz - thanks for the response! Perhaps it's simply my limited use of eXist with python then. The eulxml library was the best library I could find for interacting with Python and it doesn't play too nice with json serialization (the property mapping is superb but the rest is a nightmare). If you have other suggestions for python / eXist interaction, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: Hi Shane, glad to hear you got it working! I work with eXist directly via its natively supported XQuery language, rather than through a different language, but I know there are others who use eulxml on the [exist-open mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/projects/exist/lists/exist-open). I'd welcome you to post a question there about tips for interacting with eXist via python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a lot of playing around, I was finally able to fix this with jsonpickle and it took only 3 lines of code:

```
def toJson(self):
    jsonpickle.set_preferred_backend('simplejson')
    return jsonpickle.encode(self, unpicklable=False)
```

I used `simplejson` to eliminate some of the additional object notation that was being added and the `unpicklable` property removed the rest (I'm not sure if this would work with the default `json` backend as I didn't test it).

Now when I call toJson() on any object that inherits from this base class, I get very nice json and it works brilliantly.