# Nested object with Decimal data type and json.dumps()

Tags: python, json, object, encode, complextype

I have a a python object that is a `defaultdict` that uses a class object as its default value. This class object contains various variables, some of which are `Decimal` data types, one is a date time data type, and a couple variables are lists that in turn contain objects that have variables as `Decimal` data types, date time variables, as well as lists that can in turn have further nested objects.

```
class ReportObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.amount1 = Decimal(0.00)
        self.amount2 = Decimal(0.00)
        self.amount1_transactions = [] # This list can contain nested objects that inherit from the ReportObject
        self.amount2_transactions = [] # This list can contain nested objects that inherit from the ReportObject
        self.purchaseOrder = {}

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__dict__

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)

    def __json__(self):
        dt = {}
        for key, value in self.__dict__.items():
            if type(value) == 'list':
                dt_list = list()
                for dt_val in value:
                    dt_list.append(dt_val.__json__())
                dt[key] = dt_list
            else:
                dt[key] = str(value)
        return dt
```

The data that I'm trying to `json.dumps` is a `defaultdict` of these `ReportObjects`.

When I go to call `json.dumps(data, default: lambda o: o.__json__())` the variables that are a list are getting represented as raw strings instead of being an array of the objects in each list. Is there a cleaner way to code this custom JSON Encoding functionality? I couldn't figure out how to implement a solution from subclassing `json.JSONEncoder`.

Comment: You should use your own dunder names like `__json__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if type(value) == 'list':` will never evaluate to true, so you were *always* executing the `else` case (which stringified the `value`, as you observed); `type(value)` returns the class that `value` is an instance of, not a string describing it. The [test you want is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/152596/364696):

```
if type(value) is list:      # Only allows lists; since types are singletons, use identity test, not equality
```

or:

```
if isinstance(value, list):  # Allows list subclasses
```

Note the lack of quotes around `list`; that refers to the type, not a string describing it.

Comment: Would there be a more pythonic way to solve this by subclassing json.JSONEncoder?

Comment: @Jasonca1: It could also be done that way. See the question [Making object JSON serializable with regular encoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478287/making-object-json-serializable-with-regular-encoder) for an example of doing that (in my answer).

Comment: @martineau Is their a way to keep all the json encoding logic in the subclassed JSONEncoder rather than having to both define a special method on the object and subclassing the JSONEncoder to invoke that method when calling dumps?

Comment: @Jasonca1: Yes, there is. Please read _all_ of my answer to the question.