# Python serialize object and decode return an invalid start byte error

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, pickle

I would to serialize my object ancd encode() decode() it for manage byte/string format.
I try creating this class:

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self,uid):
        self.uid.uid
```

at this point instantiate the objest and serialize it:

```
inst_a = test(1)
pickle.dumps(inst_a)
```

return

```
b'\x80\x04\x95$\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x08__main__\x94\x8c\x04test\x94\x93\x94)\x81\x94}\x94\x8c\x03uid\x94K\x01sb.'
```

all done.
Now i would transform from byte to string but when i do:

```
pickle.dumps(ins_a).decode()
```

i get

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in 
> pickle.dumps(a).decode()
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte

why thi appen? how can i decode/encode my serialized object for transform it from byte to string and vice versa?

So many thanks indeed

Comment: Try decoding it as `encoding="latin1"` in which all byte values are valid. Might have to encode it, too. See the **Portablity to Python 3** section of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18561055/355230) of mine for an example of doing this and more details.

Answer (score 1):

`pickle.dumps` creates a byte array object (denoted by `b'...'`) which do not have to be  a valid Unicode string therefore [`decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) method on such a byte array can fail as it failed for you.

In general, the byte array from `pickle.dumps` should not ever be interpreted as string. It is an internal representation of `pickle` module and there is no guarantee to be a valid string in any encoding (and a Unicode one in particular).

If your intention is to transform the picked object back to an original object then use `pickle.loads` method on the result from `pickle.dumps`. You can of course write it to a file / read it to a file in between (as is the typical use case).