# How to calculate MD5 checksum for a unicode dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, unicode, python-unicode

I have a dictionary in python that contains unicode values in it. I want to calculate the md5 sum of this dictionary. I tried to use the answer to this question:[Computing an md5 hash of a data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417949/computing-an-md5-hash-of-a-)

```
import hashlib
import bencode
data = {'unicode_text': 'سلام'}
data_md5 = hashlib.md5(bencode.bencode(data)).hexdigest()
print data_md5
```

But the problem is that `bencode` returns this error:

```
KeyError: <type 'unicode'>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`bencode`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bencode/1.0) library seems not to support unicode objects (anyway, it's written for Python 2, and I'm guessing you're using Python 3).  How about using the built-in [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module?

```
import hashlib
import json
data = {'unicode_text': 'سلام'}
data_md5 = hashlib.md5(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True)).hexdigest()
print data_md5
```