# Deterministic, recursive hashing in python

Tags: python, hash

Python 3's default hashing function(s) isn't deterministic (hash(None) varies from run to run), and doesn't even make a best effort to generate unique id's with high probability (hash(-1)==hash(-2) is True).

Is there some other hash function that works well as a checksum (i.e. negligible probability of two data structures hashing to the same value, and returns the same result each run of python), and supports all of python's built-in datatypes, including None?

Ideally it would be in the standard library. I can pickle the object or get a string representation, but that seems unnecessarily hacky, and string representations of floats are probably very bad checksums.

I found the cryptographic hashes (md5,sha256) in the standard library, but they only operate on bytestrings.

Haskell seems to get this ~almost right in their standard library... but "Nothing::Maybe Int" and 0 both hash to 0, so it's not perfect there either.

Comment: In Python 2, hashing is deterministic. It was made to introduce some random factor after a security exploit using many known hash collisions, for example to a server, as a denial of service attack. See [here](http://www.ocert.org/advisories/ocert-2011-003.html)

Comment: Hmm. `hash(-1)` being `-2` is really strange. From -100,000,000 to 100,000,000, that's the only int whose hash value differs from itself. Weird. I wonder how/why they did that.

Comment: @StefanPochmann In the CPython source, returning `-1` is reserved for errors, so `-1` is converted to `-2` for returning the hash.

Comment: @Artyer Yeah, I just found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130454/why-do-1-and-2-both-hash-to-2-in-cpython

Comment: @Stefan, thanks for finding the reason. It sounds pretty silly to break hash, but I'm not familiar with the cPython code. Seems like at the C level, hash should be using a function argument, not the return value, to return the result. At least they didn't apply this logic to the math functions!

Comment: I thought `pprint` would help, but then realized it fails for sets. Turned that into a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016455/pprint-sorting-dicts-but-not-sets).

Answer (score 6):

<del>You can use any hash from [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) on a [pickled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) object.</del>
 [pickle.dumps not suitable for hashing](http://www.aminus.org/blogs/index.php/2007/11/03/pickle_dumps_not_suitable_for_hashing?blog=2).

You can use sorted-keys `json` with `hashlib`.

```
hashlib.md5(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True)).hexdigest()
```

Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10288255/3858507, according to AndrewWagner's comment.

By the way and *only for reference* as this causes **security vulnerabitilies**, the [PYTHONHASHSEED](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED) environment variable can be used to disable randomization of hashes throughout your application.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out. Is pickle a pure function of your data structure? Or is it sticking python version strings, timestamps, etc... in the serialized data?

Comment: I get different results for `hashlib.md5(pickle.dumps({0, 8})).hexdigest()` and `hashlib.md5(pickle.dumps({8, 0})).hexdigest()`.

Comment: Yes I tested it now too. The problem is that the pickle output itself changes because of the hash randomization. You could use `json.dumps` if it suits your needs; it supports dicts but not sets.

Comment: @nitzpo Are you sure the hash randomization is the reason? Shouldn't that only apply to different runs of the Python script? I get a difference even if I do them in a single expression: `pickle.dumps({0, 8}) == pickle.dumps({8, 0})` gives me `False`.

Comment: Ok now I tried `json`... for `json.dumps({0})` I get `TypeError: set([0]) is not JSON serializable` and for `json.dumps({0: 0, 8: 8}) == json.dumps({8: 8, 0: 0})` I get `False`.

Comment: @Stefan, I'm not surprised dictionary types don't work when you change the order; I was expecting to at least need to use OrderedDict or FrozenDict or namedtuple for key,value stuff.

Comment: This related question also uses json, which supports NaN's, and sorting dictionary entries by key. tuples and lists are serialized the same way.

Comment: json also treats namedtuples as tuples;  sort_keys seemingly has no effect, and the type of the namedtuple doesn't get serialized... So there are some issues to be aware of with collisions between instances of several built-in / standard library types...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417949/computing-an-md5-hash-of-a-data-structure

Comment: I like the solution from @AndrewWagner 's link with the `json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True)`

Comment: `sort_keys=True` kicked my ass, especially since `pprint` sorts `dicts` before printing them.  Learning is fun.