# Python 3.6: Generating a checksum of a list containing a bytes object

Tags: python

I have an LCD display that requires that display data be sent serially.

The frame for this packet is like this.

```
frame=dict(
    type=0x10,
    sequence=0,
    length=46,
    line=0,
    text=b'01234567890' * 4,
    checksum=0,
    eof=0x9F
)
```

If I generate a list of the values in a frame, I might get this.

```
>>> list(frame.values())
[16, 0, 46, 0, b'01234567890012345678900123456789001234567890', 0, 159]
```

If I sum this list to populate the checksum, an exception is raised.  I can sum the list without the bytearray and I can sum the bytes object but cannot sum it together.  It seems that this would be handy to do.

What is an elegant way to address this case?

Comment: what is the checksum algorithm? how can we help you with the current info you provided? note that most checksum algorithms give a different checksum if the data is not ordered the same way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Computing an md5 hash of a data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417949/computing-an-md5-hash-of-a-data-structure)

Comment: The checksum algorithm in this case is a simple sum of bytes.  It does not include the EOF.  I only inferred this alogiithm in my problem statement as the question is mainly pointed at how to best sum two objects both of which are summable in some case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't consider it elegant, but heres a way to do it all in one line:

```
sum(i if type(i) in(int, float) else sum(i) for i in l)
```

The issue is that sum wants a list of values that can be added together.  If you try to manually add a number and a byte array together, you'll get the same error.

Comment: I like it.  It's not as elegant as sum(frame) but it works.  Many thanks.  I'll check this answer later unless something more elegant shows up. ;-)

Comment: Any time.  Note that this line will fail if your list contains types that sum would normally fail on.

Comment: If you iterate over a bytes object, you get a sequence of ints.  Seems like summing a list of ints containing also a bytes or bytearray should continuing the summing.